# Obtaining a unique top-down list of folders in python

Tags: python, unique, directory, os.walk

Given these folders

```
s:\test\zoneA\UnitA
s:\test\zoneB\UnitA
s:\test\zoneB\UnitB\Item_1
```

I would like to pass to a function 's:\test' and get unique bottom list of folders

Resulting in what you see above... 3 entries. Instead, when I use my function

```
import os
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('S:\\\test'):
    for nm in dirs:
        print os.path.join(top, nm)
```

I get...

```
S:\test\zoneA
S:\test\zoneB
S:\test\zoneA\UnitA
S:\test\zoneB\UnitA
S:\test\zoneB\UnitB
S:\test\zoneB\UnitB\Item_1
```

Is there a way to get the bottom folder list ? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want are folders without subfolders?

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('S:\\\test'):
    if not dirs:
        print path
```